# How do I install the latest gcc on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, gcc, g++

How do I install the latest `gcc` on FreeBSD and set up the system so that this latest version would be used to compile further programs?

At the moment of this writing, the latest release of `gcc` is version 4.9.0. And I use FreeBSD 10.0.

I actually need `g++`, the C++ compiler; but I need to install something like `gcc49` package for it, right?

Comment: Dp you want to compile all ports with GCC or do you need just GCC?

Comment: I would like `gcc` to compile my software. And maybe the ports I would install after that, if that can be done.

Comment: Remember that there are are different branches you can download software from on FreeBSD: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433876/128489

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can install GCC 4.9  by building it from ports with

```
cd /usr/ports/lang/gcc49; make install clean
```

or if you have `portmaster`

```
portmaster -DHB lang/gcc49
```

or if you prefer packages with

```
pkg install lang/gcc49
```

If you change `lang/gcc49` to `lang/gcc` you will install the most recent stable version of GCC currently this is GCC 4.7.

When you want to build all your ports with GCC instead of Clang you have to edit `/etc/make.conf` and add

```
.if !empty(.CURDIR:M/usr/ports/*) && exists(/usr/local/bin/gcc49)
CC=gcc49
CXX=g++49
CPP=cpp49
.endif
```

and edit `/etc/libmap.conf` and add there

```
libgcc_s.so.1   gcc49/libgcc_s.so.1
libgomp.so.1    gcc49/libgomp.so.1
libobjc.so.3    gcc49/libobjc.so.4
libssp.so.0     gcc49/libssp.so.0
libstdc++.so.6  gcc49/libstdc++.so.6
```

Here is an [article from FreeBSD.org](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/custom-gcc/article.html) which explains this in more detail.

But you don't really need GCC for the ports, all ports that already depend on GCC will use GCC.

#### Edit:

And yeah `g++` will be installed with all GCC ports.

Comment: Note that now `lang/gcc5` also exists.

Comment: and `lang/gcc7` (December 2017)

Comment: lang/gcc would install the newest version of gcc.

Comment: @user917099 Not always some times lang/gcc is one or two versions behind. At the time when the answer was written `lang/gcc` was not pointing at `lang/gcc49`.