# How to install the latest version of software in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, version, pkg

The [ports repository (svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/)](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/net/haproxy/)  shows haproxy is `version 1.7.10` but `pkg search haproxy` gives me

> haproxy-1.7.9                  Reliable, high performance TCP/HTTP load balancer

It suggests that `pkg search` uses other source instead of FreeBSD ports. Is that true?

How can I install the latest version of haproxy-1.7.10 in FreeBSD (preferably using a binary package)?

Comment: Install from the [ports collection](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/ports-using.html).

Comment: @RichardSmith This is a bad advice. OP clearly have been using packages and mixing packages and ports is a bad idea, generally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess that you're installing packages from the *quarterly* branch.

The *quarterly* branch does not always have the latest software, which is why it is regarded more stable than the *latest* branch. The newest one is 2018Q1 currently and as you can see [here](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/branches/2018Q1/net/haproxy/Makefile?revision=457769&view=markup) the newest haproxy is not there yet.

You may switch to the *latest* branch as described in the ["*PKG Repository Changed to Quarterly in 10.2?*" thread](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/pkg-repository-changed-to-quarterly-in-10-2.52843/#post-296554) on FreeBSD Forums.

Put the following code into `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf`:

```
FreeBSD: {
    url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest"
}
```

It is generally recommended to store your installed software configuration files under `/usr/local`. This way it is easier to separate those settings from the configuration files of software shipped with FreeBSD. [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=8) is somewhat special. Although being an essential utility it is not installed by default (it has to be bootstraped using [pkg(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=7)). This is why its configuration files fit both `/etc` and `/usr/local/etc`.

---

See also:

- [pkg.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg.conf&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports)

Comment: The logic regarding `/etc` vs `/usr/local/etc` is more about what is related to base system (FreeBSD without any port/packages) and what is port/packages stuff.

Comment: @Ouki Is it better now?

Answer (score 5):

Check what package repository are you using:

```
cat /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf
```

Make sure you have `url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest"` in there, not `quarterly`.