# Change between `quarterly` and `latest` package set used by `pkg` tool in FreeBSD

Tags: package-management, freebsd, pkg

The `pkg` tool in FreeBSD is usually set to draw upon either the `quarterly` or `latest` package set. The `latest` set may churn more often with updates, while the `quarterly` is meant to be more stable but not the very latest<sup>†</sup>.

➥ How can I switch from one to the other?

---

<sup>†</sup> Or [maybe not](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/latest-vs-quarterly-on-pkg-freebsd-org.61343/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [discussed](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/pkg-repository-changed-to-quarterly-in-10-2.52843/) in the forums, in FreeBSD 10.2, the default changed from `latest` to `quarterly`. You may choose to use either.

To quote the 10.2 [*Release Notes*](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.2R/relnotes.html#releng-changes):

> The default pkg(8) repository set in /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf now defaults to the quarterly package set. To use the latest branch (as was the previous default), the comment at the top of /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf explains how to disable the default repository and specify an alternative repository. [r285830] (Sponsored by The FreeBSD Foundation)

The contents of that .conf file in FreeBSD 11.2:

```json
# $FreeBSD: releng/11.2/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf 333474 2018-05-10 23:58:33Z gjb $
#
# To disable this repository, instead of modifying or removing this file,
# create a /usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf file:
#
#   mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/pkg/repos
#   echo "FreeBSD: { enabled: no }" > /usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf
#

FreeBSD: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/quarterly",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  signature_type: "fingerprints",
  fingerprints: "/usr/share/keys/pkg",
  enabled: yes
}
```

As noted in that quote, you need not modify the original file. Instead, create a new file in a different location, based on the original. Then change the “quarterly” to “latest” within that [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)-like text at the bottom.

```bash
mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/pkg/repos
echo "FreeBSD: { enabled: no }" > /usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf
```

Then change the “quarterly” to “latest” in the `url:` line of that [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)-like text at the bottom.

```json
…
FreeBSD: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest",
…
```

For more info about the locations of these files, see [this Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433876/56752) by Mateusz Piotrowski on a related Question.